# mysql latest with Docker Desktop 3.3.0 (62916)

Tags: mysql, macos, docker

i keep getting the following error trying launch the latest mysql:

2021-04-12 20:02:30+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.

2021-04-12 20:02:31+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'

2021-04-12 20:02:31+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.

2021-04-12 20:02:31+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: mysqld failed while attempting to check config

```
command was: mysqld --verbose --help --log-bin-index=/tmp/tmp.1KuUrWTbii

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 92: /dev/null: Permission denied
```

dockerfile:
#ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/init"]

this was working before I updated Docker Desktop to 3.3.0, i think the previous was 3.2.3? nothing changed with my config or setup.

Comment: try to run it with `sudo` at first of your command

Comment: @Joseph no change, same error as above. as i mentioned, nothing changed in my dockerfile, the docker desktop updated, I probably the mysql, not sure..

Comment: This looks like a docker bug associated with your update.